# How do I wait for a query to finish before making another query with graphql?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graph, apollo, react-apollo

I have a query called `GET_ME` and another one called `GET_USER_NOTIFICATIONS`. Second one it's looking for user id which will come from first query. My problem is that sometimes I receive `[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'o.props.getMe.me._id')]`

Here is my code for this:

```
export default compose(
  withApollo,
  graphql(GET_ME, { name: "getMe" }),
  graphql(GET_USER_NOTIFICATIONS, {
    name: "notification",
    skip: props => !props.getMe || !props.getMe.me,
    options: props => ({
      variables: { r_id: props.getMe.me._id }
    })
  })
)(Notifications);
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try doing:

```
variables: { r_id: props.getMe && props.getMe.me ? props.getMe.me._id : null }
// I use "null" in case the object doesn't exists. 
// You can use value that your graphql needs.
```

(you could also use lodash for simplicity `_.get(...)`)

The error suggests that it's executing the variables assignment although you have set the query to be skipped. But at the time of the assignment either `getMe` or `getMe.me` is "undefined".

If that doesn't help, you can use the **Render props** Apollo components inside of the render method. That way, you can guarantee you can't set the variable without getting access to `getMe.me._id`.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy :)